# Informix DELETE query taking long time

Tags: informix

In production, I am facing this problem.

There is a `delete` which is taking long time to execute and is finally throwing SQL error of `-243`.
I got the query using `onstat -g`.

Is there any way to find out what is causing it to take this much time and finally error out?

It uses `COMMITTED READ` isolation.

This is causing high Informix cpu usage as well.

**EDIT**

**Environment** - Informix 9.2 on Solaris

I do not see any issue related to indexes or application logic, but I suspect some informix corruption.
The session holds 8 locks on different tables while executing this `DELETE` query.
But, I do not see any locks on the table on which the `delete` is performed.

Would it be something like, informix is unable to get lock on the table?

Comment: Have you tried running the `DELETE FROM Table WHERE ...` as `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ...` (for any suitable subset of all the columns) and reviewed the query plan?  How fast does that work?  Does the table have blob columns, or smart blob columns?  What is the query plan given for DELETE; how does it compare with the SELECT plan?  Is there an index missing that would speed this up?  How many indexes are on the table?  Are there so many that reducing the number of indexes would improve performance? Which version of Informix?  Running on which platform?

Comment: Table has a group index on 2 columns and the delete is also based on that 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

DELETE doesn't care about your isolation level. You are getting 243 because another process is locking the table while you're trying to run your delete operation.

I would put your delete into an SP and commit each Xth record:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE tmp_delete_sp (
  p_commit_records INTEGER
) 
RETURNING 
  INTEGER, 
  VARCHAR(64);

DEFINE l_current_count INTEGER;

SET LOCK MODE TO WAIT 5; -- Wait 5 seconds if another process is locking the table.

BEGIN WORK;

FOREACH WITH HOLD
  SELECT .....

  DELETE FROM table WHERE ref = ^^ Ref from above;

  LET l_current_count = l_current_count + 1;

  IF (l_current_count >= p_commit_records) THEN
     COMMIT WORK;
     BEGIN WORK;
     LET l_current_count = 0;
  END IF;

END FOREACH;

COMMIT WORK;

RETURN 0, 'Deleted records';
END PROCEDURE;
```

Some syntax issues there, but it's a good starting block for you. Remember, inserts and updates get incrementally slower as you use more logical logs.

Answer (score 0):

Informix was restarted ungracefully many times, which led to informix instability.
This was the root cause.